# Windows API behind "virtual files" in OneDrive

Tags: winapi, onedrive, virtualfilesystem

OneDrive folder can show files as-if present, but they are not on disk.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/save-disk-space-with-onedrive-files-on-demand-for-windows-10-0e6860d3-d9f3-4971-b321-7092438fb38e

I'd like to create a similar folder programmatically.
What API does OneDrive client use?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cfapi/build-a-cloud-file-sync-engine

Comment: I don't know what solution OneDrive uses, but the [Windows Projected File System (ProjFS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/projfs/projected-file-system) can be used to implement this.

Answer (score 5):

From official documentation: [Build a Cloud Sync Engine that Supports Placeholder Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cfapi/build-a-cloud-file-sync-engine)

> Windows 10 version 1709 introduced the cloud files API. This API is a
> new platform that formalizes support for sync engines. The cloud files
> API provides support for sync engines in a way that offers many new
> benefits to developers and end users.
>
> The cloud files API contains the following native Win32 APIs and
> Windows Runtime (WinRT) APIs:
>
> Cloud Filter API: This native Win32 API provides functionality at the
> boundary between the user mode and the file system. This API handles
> the creation and management of placeholder files and directories.
> Windows.Storage.Provider namespace: This WinRT API enables
> applications to configure the cloud storage provider and register the
> sync root with the operating system.  Note
>
> The cloud files API does not currently support implementing cloud sync
> engines in UWP apps. Cloud sync engines must be implemented in desktop
> apps.

Note that the Cloud Filter API provides you the API to manipulate Windows 10 1709's NTFS placeholders, but it will not help you build a "sync engine" at all... There's no notion of "synchronization" in this API.